# Two words from Shinya Shokudou

Tags: words, etymology

I have two questions about the TV series Shinya Shokudo. The show focuses on a midnight diner, its chef, known as "The Master", and his involvement with his customers. When the master is taking an order from a customer, he always says something like「あよ」(1). When he is serving a meal, he says something like 「おまち」(2).

I cannot find both these words in the dictionaries. I would like to know the origin of those two words and the correct writing.

You can listen to it here:

(1) https://youtu.be/4bt8JOmUQTA?t=227

(2) https://youtu.be/4bt8JOmUQTA?t=820

**EDIT** Since I got asked to include what I think the translation/meaning could be, I would say obviously (1) is something along the lines "allright, sure" and (2) is something along the lines "here you go". (2) could also be some short form of お待ち遠様 but I'm not sure. That's why I was asking in the first place :)

Comment: Welcome to JLSE!  We are not set up as a bulk translation/transcription service.  If you would like to avoid getting this question as closed as off topic, please include your translation of what you think they are saying so that we can better help you .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- (1) This is not あよ but [あいよ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%88).
- (2) お待ち is indeed short for [お待ちどおさま](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8A%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1%E9%81%A0%E6%A7%98).

Both of these are used mainly by a friendly server or a chef in a private informal restaurant. Chefs of sushi restaurants may say these, too. You will never hear these in chain restaurants and classy Western-style restaurants where proper keigo is expected.